# Radius of convergence of a general series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If the radius of convergence of $\sum a_n x^n$ is $R$, prove that the radius of convergence of $\sum a_n x^{2n}$ is $R^{1/2}$.

What I tried to do is look at
$$\sum \sqrt{a_n} x^n $$

Then we get that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right)^{1/2}=R'$$ and tried relating $R'$ and $R$ but I have a feeling like I can't say for certain $\sum\sqrt{a_n}x^n$ even converges absolutely. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x^2=y$. Note that if $|y|\gt R$, then $\sum a_ny^n$ diverges, and if $|y|\lt R$, then $\sum a_ny_n$ converges.

Thus if $x^2\gt R$, then $\sum a_n x^{2n}$ diverges, and if $x^2\lt R$, then $\sum a_nx^{2n}$ converges.

Thus if $|x|\gt\sqrt{R}$, we have divergence, and if $|X|\lt \sqrt{R}$, we have convergence, and therefore the radius of convergence is $\sqrt{R}$.

Comment: I haven't reached that part yet, unfortunately. This is from the very first section of power series and intervals of convergence. We basically only know to find intervals of convergence using $\lim|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|=R$

Comment: @MITjanitor;  I have given a more elementary argument.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the radius of convergence, $a_nx^n\to0$ for every $|x|\lt R$ and $a_nx^n\not\to0$ for every $|x|\gt R$. Thus,  $a_nx^{2n}\to0$ for every $|x|\lt\sqrt{R}$ and $a_nx^{2n}\not\to0$ for every $|x|\gt\sqrt{R}$. Using the definition again, this proves that the  radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_na_nx^{2n}$ is $\sqrt{R}$.

Note that the characterization of the radius of convergence using the ratios $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ does not apply to every series and that the well known formula based on $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ applies to every series but is rather a characterization than a definition.

Comment: I appreciate the added portion at the bottom!